# Complete example on findByAttributes in Yii

Tags: yii

I am appreciated if someone shows a complete example on how to use findByAttributes in Yii framework.

Official doc @ http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByAttributes-detail

```
public CActiveRecord findByAttributes(array $attributes, mixed $condition='', array $params=array ( ))
```

I know how to use $attributes. I do not see a good reason to use **$condition** and **$params** in findByAttributes.

Please tell me under what scenario, you use them in findByAttributes.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it was included to match similar function in other frameworks and best used when your query is mostly an array of column names like `array('dept_id'=>2,'active'=>'y')` -- there might be times in your program where it's easier to pass an array in this format rather than having to re-write them into conditions. You might want to add additional conditions in the **$condition** paramater or ones that **$attributes** may not support like `project_name LIKE "foo%"`.

**$params** are used here like other query types, to bind condition values to column types for filtering.

see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record

> Info: When a query condition is about
>   matching some columns with the
>   specified values, we can use
>   findByAttributes(). We let the
>   $attributes parameters be an array of
>   the values indexed by the column
>   names. In some frameworks, this task
>   can be achieved by calling methods
>   like findByNameAndTitle. Although this
>   approach looks attractive, it often
>   causes confusion, conflict and issues
>   like case-sensitivity of column names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any piece of codes as examples?

Answer (score 1):

example of **findByAttributes()** :

```
$modelname->findByAttributes(array('fieldName1'=>$value1,'fieldName2'=>$value2));
```